# 01 1011 - 11 1101 = ? use 2's complement

Tags: binary

I'm trying to figure out this doozie: 01 1011 - 11 1101

use 2's complement to solve, 6bits signed.

This is what I tried:

range of 6bits: -32 to 31

01 1011 = 27

11 1101 = -29

27 -(-29) = 56 (overflow)

11 1101 -- 2s complement --> 10 0011

so

01 1011 + 10  0011 = (missing bit)11 1110 = -2!

Any luck?

Comment: Very tough homework by the way)

Comment: He didn't give us any examples of what to do when positiveNum - negativeNum in 2's complement... I can't find an answer of this case anywhere.

Comment: @Artiom: Homework is fine if the questioner has made an effort and is asking a question about the effort they've made, which is clearly the case above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I figured it out:

my first mistake was that 11 1101 is not -29 but -3.

SO:

01 1011 = 27

11 1101 = -3

27 -(-3) = 30

I can do a reverse 2's complement of -3 which is:

11 1101 - 1 = 11 1100

then I flip 11 1100 which gives me 00 0011.

so

01 1011 + 00 0011 = 01 1110 = 30

:)